# AngularJS - validating available email on element bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, bind, directive

I am using a 'required' and 'email' validators on the 'email' input field. The validators make use of parsers and formatters and they work fine. However, I also have some validation on 'bind' event.

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('simpleRepairApp')
  .directive('uniqueEmail', function (Checker) {
    return {
      require:'ngModel',
      restrict:'A',
      link:function ($scope, element, attrs, model) {    
        var last = '';
        var current = '';    
        element.bind('blur', function() {    
          current = element.val();    
          console.log(current, last);    
          if(current !== last){
            Checker.email({ email:current }).then(
              function(response) {
                model.$setValidity('uniqueEmail', response.available);
              }
            );
          }    
          last = current;    
        });    
      }
  };
});
```

I need to check if the email already exists in the database or not after user clicks out of the field (I do not want to check upon every key press or change).

The problem I am having is, after the unique validation is performed, it shows the unique error message, but after you type to correct the email, the model value stays undefined. You have to click out of the input, then the value in the model in defined again.

Anyone can help me solve this, it is driving me nuts!:)

WORKING SOLUTION:

```
angular.module('simpleRepairApp')
  .directive('emailUnique', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: ['form', 'ngModel'],
      scope: {
        'form': '=form',
        'model': '=ngModel',
        'labelClass': '@',
        'inputClass': '@'
      },
      compile: function(element, attrs)
      {
        if (!attrs.labelClass) { attrs.labelClass = 'col-sm-4'; }
        if (!attrs.inputClass) { attrs.inputClass = 'col-sm-8'; }
        attrs.required = attrs.required == 'true';
      },
      controller: function($scope, Checker) {

        $scope.checkEmail = function() {

          var email = $scope.form.email.$viewValue;
          var checkField = $scope.form.emailCheck;

          Checker.email({ email:email }).then(
            function(response) {
              checkField.$setValidity('unique', response.available);
              $scope.form.$setValidity('check', true);
              checkField.hasVisit = true;
            }
          );

        };

        $scope.setUnchecked = function() {
          console.log($scope.form);
          $scope.form.emailCheck.hasVisited = false;
          $scope.form.$setValidity('check', false);
          $scope.form.emailCheck.$setValidity('unique', true);

        };

      },
      template: '<div ng-class="{ \'has-error\' : !form.email.$valid || !form.emailCheck.$valid }">' +
                  '<label class="{{ labelClass }} control-label required" for="email" translate>E-mail</label>' +
                  '<div class="{{ inputClass }}">' +
                    '<input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" id="email" ng-model="model" ng-change="setUnchecked()" ng-blur="checkEmail()" ng-required="true" autocomplete="off">' +
                    '<div class="help-block" ng-show="(!form.email.$valid || !form.emailCheck.$valid) && !form.email.$pristine">' +
                      '<div ng-messages="form.email.$error">' +
                        '<div ng-message="required"><span translate>Please enter your e-mail.</span></div>' +
                        '<div ng-message="email"><span translate>Please enter a valid e-mail.</span></div>' +
                      '</div> ' +
                      '<div ng-messages="form.emailCheck.$error">' +
                        '<div ng-message="check"><span translate>E-mail will be checked upon blur.</span></div>' +
                        '<div ng-message="unique"><span translate>This e-mail is already in use.</span></div>' +
                      '</div> ' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<input name="emailCheck" type="hidden" class="form-control" ng-model="checked">' +
                    '<div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.emailCheck.$error" ng-show="!form.emailCheck.$valid">' +
                    '</div>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</div>'
    };
  });
```

Comment: good job.. maybe you can start working on migrating that parsed up html, into an html file, and replace the word "template" with "templateUrl" :-D

Comment: Yes, I know it is a good practice to make a separate file with html content and I usually do it. The thing is, I have a lot of validators like this and some other form fragments and I would end up with a million of files, so sometimes I believe it is a better way to make everything in one place / file, so it is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be complicating things a bit by making a directive, why don't you simply add a watcher to your controller?

**Note: I'm not familiar if any of these methods will work for you, but I'm adding them as an illustrative purpose of not binding to the "blur" event, but rather have the events get triggered when the MODEL changes. Which is what angular is designed to do. I'm also making an assumption that your Checker is handling the promises correctly**

**First alternative method** (using $watch)

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="text" required />
</form>
```

Then in your ng-app controller:

```
function isNullOrUndefined(value) {
    return (value == 'undefined' || value == null);
}

//listener on the ng-model='text', waiting for the data to get dirty
$scope.$watch('text', function (newValue, oldValue) {
   if (newValue != oldValue)
   {
       var truthyVal = !(isNullOrUndefined(newValue));
       if (truthyVal) {
           //angular's way of checking validity as well
           //$scope.myForm.text.$valid
           Checker.email({ email:current }).then(
           function(response) {
              model.$setValidity('textErr', response.available);
          }
       }
   }
}, true);
```

**Second alternative method** (using ng-change):

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="text" ng-change="checkEmail()" required />
</form>

$scope.checkEmail = function(){
    Checker.email({ email:current }).then(
       function(response) {
          model.$setValidity('textErr', response.available);
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried your approaches, but still the same 'bug' occuring. After .$setValidity, the field colors red, and when I type the next character or change the input, the model value disappears.

Comment: keep it the way it is with one of the approach.. just try not to use jquery binding too much. What happens when you debug response.available? Does it give back a boolean? or a string boolean? Like there's a difference between "true" and true.

Comment: Also give the first parameter a different name than uniqueEmail. From the docs on $setValidity, the first parameter has to be an unused variable that will receive the invalid error. It's a validationErrorKey.. so in my example.. textErr, will result in "ng-valid-text-err" and "ng-invalid-text-err" class. So don't make it the same name as your directive.

Comment: @tomazahlin any luck?

Comment: Well, I have tried both of your suggestions and they are good practice, but still it did not help with my initial problem. I have completely rewritten the directive and got it working. I will update my initial question with a solution that I found effective.

Comment: That is great news, I'd love to check it out when you post it.

Comment: I have posted it above, if you would like to check;)

Comment: nice.. do you think it was the $scope.form.$setValidity that allowed it to work?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but it definitely was something around $setValidity, which caused the model value to become undefined, but it did not become 'defined' again, when the view value was again valid. I solved that, by creating a hidden input and set the validity on it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are binding on the blur event, the validation won't work the way you want. You will have to click out of the field before that function can run. If you indeed want it to validate when they finish typing the email, then you will have to bind to some sort of key event.

My suggestion is to bind to keyup, and only do the server-side check when the email address appears to be of valid syntax.